# Python math.sinh with input()

Tags: python, math

```
import math
var = input("Give some numbers!")
print(math.sinh(var))
```

It doesn't give me an answer if I put something in? Can someone help me?

Comment: I have used import math!

Comment: `input` returns a string, and `math.sinh` requires a float, so you need to convert the string response into a float as Manby suggests.  You could convert it to an `int` as kingpanda419 suggested, but this will artificially restrict the values you can provide to integers only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the input into a `float` after it is received.

In python, by default, inputs are recieved as **strings**. `math.sinh` will only take **numerical inputs** (`int` and `float` types), therefore you need to convert the input to a `float` before storing it in `var`.

Try:

```
import math
var = float(input("Give some numbers!"))
print(math.sinh(var))
```

Comment: Thank you I thought I already did that before!

Answer (score 0):

I think your inputing value type is NAN.
so i suggest that
`var=int(input("Give some numbers!"))`